# How to implement select so that I can access selelected value in my code when user clicks submit button

Tags: jquery, python, html, python-2.7, flask

I am making simple uploader based on Flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/), everything is working from getting file to saving it. My question is how to implement select so that I can access selelected value in my code when user clicks submit button, preferably user must select one of the values.

**In template**

```
        <div>
          <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;">
            <a class='btn btn-primary' href='javascript:;'>
                Choose document
                <input type="file" style='position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;min-width: 100%;min-height: 100%;font-size: 999px;
                text-align: right;filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0;outline: none;background: white;cursor: inherit;display: block;' 
                name="file" id ="Mfile" size="40" onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'>
            </a>
            &nbsp;
            <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
        </div>
        <br/>
    <br/>
    <select name = "choose" class="form-control">
      <option value="cop">Computer programming</option>
      <option value="bio">Biology</option>
      <option value="mth">Math</option>
      <option value="soc">Sociology</option>
      <option value="psy">Psychology </option>
    </select>
    <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i> Submit
            </button>
      </form>
      </div>
```

**In code**

```
@main.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Have you seen any of [the documention on the `request` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object)?  If so, what is unclear about it (hint `request.form['choose']`)?

Comment: Thank you, problem solved, could you please post it in a formal way  so I can accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access any user-provided value in Flask you can use the [`request` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data).  `request` is a thread-local tied to the request context that you can use to access:

- Query-string parameters via [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) (e. g. `/some/url?these=params&right=here`)

  ```
  request.args['these']  # "params"
  request.args['right']  # "here"
  ```
- URL-encoded body parameters from form posts, etc. via [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form):

  ```
  <!-- in your html -->
  <form action="/do-stuff" method="post">
      <input name="these" value="params">
      <input name="right" value="here">
      <input type="submit">
  </form>


  # In your script
  request.form['these']  # "params"
  request.form['right']  # "here"
  ```
- JSON-encoded bodies via `request.get_json()`, cookie data via `request.cookies` and more (detailed in [the API documentation for `flask.Request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data))